# Failed to generate dataobject with mybatis generator（Error Info：Communications link failure）

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin, mybatis, mybatis-generator

I'm a rookie in JAVA, and I'm searching for a long time on net. But the answer didn't work. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.

Firstly I'll show the **version infomation**:

JAVA：1.8.0_321
MySQL:5.7.37
mysql-connector-java:5.1.46
Maven:3.8.1
Windows 11

Next it's the **configuration information** about mybatis generator:

Mybatis generator related in**settings.xml**:

```
<localRepository>D:\桌面\qzh\repository</localRepository>
```

Mybatis generator related in **pom.xml**:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.46</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.jexcelapi</groupId>
            <artifactId>jxl</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.12</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.python</groupId>
            <artifactId>jython-standalone</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mybatis.spring.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.mybatis.generator</groupId>
                <artifactId>mybatis-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.7</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.mybatis.generator</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mybatis-generator-core</artifactId>
                        <version>1.3.7</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                        <version>5.1.46</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>tk.mybatis</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mapper</artifactId>
                        <version>3.5.3</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>mybatis generator</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <!--<phase>deploy</phase>-->
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>

                <configuration>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                    <overwrite>false</overwrite>
                    <configurationFile>
                        src/main/resources/mybatis-generator.xml
                    </configurationFile>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
</build>
```

**application.yml**:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    druid:
      filters: stat
      driver-class-name: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
      url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/X?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&allowMultiQueries=true&useSSL=false&serverTimezone=GMT%2B8
      username: root
      password: 123456
```

**mybatis-generator.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE generatorConfiguration
        PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD MyBatis Generator Configuration 1.0//EN"
        "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-generator-config_1_0.dtd">

<generatorConfiguration>
    <classPathEntry location="D:/桌面/qzh/repository/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.46/mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar"/>

    <context id="DB2Tables" targetRuntime="MyBatis3">
        <commentGenerator>
            <property name="suppressDate" value="true"/>
            <property name="suppressAllComments" value="true"/>
        </commentGenerator>
        <jdbcConnection driverClass="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
                        connectionURL="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/X"
                        userId="root" password="123456">
        </jdbcConnection>
        <javaTypeResolver>
            <property name="forceBigDecimals" value="false"/>
        </javaTypeResolver>
        <javaModelGenerator targetPackage="com.example.demo.dataobject" targetProject="src/main/java">
            <property name="enableSubPackages" value="true"/>
            <property name="trimStrings" value="false"/>
        </javaModelGenerator>
        <sqlMapGenerator targetPackage="mapping" targetProject="src/main/resources">
            <property name="enableSubPackages" value="true"/>
        </sqlMapGenerator>

        <javaClientGenerator type="XMLMAPPER" targetPackage="com.example.demo.dao" targetProject="src/main/java">
            <property name="enableSubPackages" value="true"/>
        </javaClientGenerator>
    </context>
</generatorConfiguration>
```

When I run the command "**mybatis-generator:generate -e**" I got the following error:

> [INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
> [INFO] Scanning for projects...
> [INFO] 
> [INFO] --------------------------< com.example:demo >--------------------------
> [INFO] Building demo 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
> [INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
> [INFO] 
> [INFO] --- mybatis-generator-maven-plugin:1.3.7:generate (default-cli) @ demo ---
> [INFO] Connecting to the Database
> Sun Dec 25 15:53:44 GMT+08:00 2022 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
> [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
> [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
> [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
> [INFO] Total time:  1.134 s
> [INFO] Finished at: 2022-12-25T15:53:44+08:00
> [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.mybatis.generator:mybatis-generator-maven-plugin:1.3.7:generate (default-cli) on project demo: Communications link failure
> [ERROR] 
> [ERROR] The last packet successfully received from the server was 283 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 279 milliseconds ago.
> [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
> org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.mybatis.generator:mybatis-generator-maven-plugin:1.3.7:generate (default-cli) on project demo: Communications link failure
>
> The last packet successfully received from the server was 283 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 279 milliseconds ago.
> at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
> at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
> at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
> at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
> at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
> at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
> at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
> at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
> at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
> at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
> at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
> at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
> at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
> at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
> at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
> at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
> at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
> at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:47)
> Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Communications link failure
>
> The last packet successfully received from the server was 283 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 279 milliseconds ago.
> at org.mybatis.generator.maven.MyBatisGeneratorMojo.execute (MyBatisGeneratorMojo.java:239)
> at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
> at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
> at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
> at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
> at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
> at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
> at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
> at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
> at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
> at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
> at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
> at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
> at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
> at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
> at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
> at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
> at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
> at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
> at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:47)
> [ERROR] 
> [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
> [ERROR] 
> [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
> [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

I've tried to solve the problem, but what I was searching it's all about "how to connect MySQL". however, I just need to connect my local MySQL and my connection on Navicat is feasible, so I think the problem is not with MySQL.I'm looking forward to getting a right solution.

Thanks in advance.

I've tried to change the url with suffix:

```
?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&allowMultiQueries=true&useSSL=false&serverTimezone=GMT%2B8
```

But error information still has a warn:

> Tue Dec 27 11:23:25 GMT+08:00 2022 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.

I don't know if this means the url didn't work

Comment: When you specify `connectionURL` in `mybatis-generator.xml`,  `&` must be written as `&amp;` because it's XML. e.g. `?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8&amp;allowMultiQueries=....`

Comment: @ave Thank for your comment. I've tried your method and it solved the problem. I mistakenly put the suffix in `application.yml` when specifying the URL and it didn't take effect. Thank you for your answer and have a nice day！